# Komodo Edit: How to refresh the directory tree status

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I've tried "Refresh Status" from the context menu, but this doesn't work for me. When I have deleted or added files in the tree display directory, it doesn't display them in the directory tree until I close Komodo Edit, and restart it. This is too bad.

Is there something I'm missing? I hope someone could give me a hand.

Comment: I too would *love* to know this.

Comment: @mlzboy: do you get any error while doing so? what exactly happens?

Comment: @Harry Joy: No error, just nothing happens. The tree doesn't refresh until you restart the editor.

Comment: @mlzboy,@Karpie: which version of komodo are you using?

Comment: @Harry Joy: I'm using 6.1.0 under Linux.

Comment: @Karpie: are you using dual screen means two monitors sharing one cpu?

Comment: @Harry Joy: Just the one monitor here.

Comment: Same problem, to overcome it I have to connect to a different FTP or SFTP and then re-connect to the one I want to refresh the view. Annoying!
Seems to happen only with some FTP accounts.

Comment: I have same issue in Komodo 9 (had it with 8 and 8.5 before that).

Answer (score 2):

I get this problem sometimes too. Collapsing the directory, then refreshing its status, and expanding it again sometimes works.

A more reliable method is to change the root directory in the Places sidebar and then back to where you want to be.

Not perfect, but quicker than reopening Komodo Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have complete C++ support on your machine? One known issue in Kommodo is

> Komodo may not start up correctly on
> some Linux systems if C++
> compatibility libraries have not been
> installed. On Fedora and Red Hat
> systems, install the
> "compat-libstdc++" package. On SuSE,
> install the "compat" package. On
> Gentoo, as root, run emerge
> lib-compat. This is not thought to be
> a problem on Debian systems.

This bugs is listed [here](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/releases/ide.html).

May be this can help you in solving your problem.

Comment: I'm running a Debian (Ubuntu) system, and I still see the issue.

Comment: @Karpie: if you are using Debian(Ubuntu) then all should work fine. There is no bug regarding Debian in builds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JSdrivetree](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/jstreedrive) or [remotedrivetree](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/remote-drive-tree) extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the root directory (top left) and click "Refresh View".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: What do you mean this does not provide an answer? It is exactly the correct answer. It is one thing refresh status and another refresh view. Try it yourself. If I was allowed I would also post a picture.

Comment: Sorry - that's a canned message provided by the review process, it's pretty general. Specific problems with your answer to follow...

Comment: You've provided an answer to a 5 year old question that already has answers, so you should consider providing justification for the update. The OP didn't provide the version of Komodo they were using, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't - you can be sure it's changed in the intervening years. A screenshot would help, and while you can't post one yet you can upload it to imgur and put the link as text (or provide the image ID); a higher rep user will usually edit your post to inline it for you. (Reply and I'll do so.) Without additional context though, your answer is more suitable as a comment.